# Can I use If in a UDF?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to use a Scalar UDF, to implement a business rule that states all offer values attract the following commission:

• First Quarter (Jan – Mar) 10% commission

• Second Quarter (Apr - Jun) 15% commission

• Second Quarter (Jul – Sep) 20% commission

• Fourth Quarter (Oct – Dec) 25% commission

The UDF function should accept the offer value, calculate the commission and return the commission fee that is to be paid to the employee.

I have a table called Campaign Offer.

```
Create Table Campaign_Offer
(
       Offer_id         integer identity(1,1) primary key,

       Offer_date           Date        ,

       Customer_id          int ,

       Offer_value          money       ,

       Product_name     varchar(20) ,

       Acceptance_status    varchar(3)  ,

       Employee_ID          char(10)    ,

    Constraint CustomerID foreign key (Customer_id) references marketing_list(Id),
    Constraint EmployeeID foreign key (Employee_ID) references Employee(Employee_id),
    Constraint AcceptanceStatus Check (Acceptance_status in ('yes', 'no'))
)
```

I was trying to do it here

```
Create Function OfferCommission (@OfferValue money,@OfferDate date)
Returns money
As
Begin
if @OfferDate between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'
Begin
Return @OfferValue*0.1
End
else
if @OfferDate between '04/01/2015' and '06/31/2015'
Begin
Return @OfferValue*0.15
End
else
if @OfferDate between '07/01/2015' and '09/31/2015'
Begin
Return @OfferValue*0.2
End
else
if @OfferDate between '09/01/2015' and '12/31/2015'
Begin
Return @OfferValue*0.25
End
End
```

Comment: Case is much better than if for your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
Create Function OfferCommission (@OfferValue money,@OfferDate date)
Returns money
As
Begin
 DECLARE @result MONEY;

 SELECT @result = 
   CASE 
    WHEN @OfferDate between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue * 0.1
    WHEN @OfferDate between '04/01/2015' and '06/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue * 0.15
    WHEN @OfferDate between '07/01/2015' and '09/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue * 0.2
    WHEN @OfferDate between '09/01/2015' and '12/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue * 0.25
    ELSE NULL
    END;

  RETURN @result;
END
```

You can use **`CHOOSE`** for even shorter solution for **SQL SERVER 2012+**.

```
Create Function OfferCommission (@OfferValue money,@OfferDate date)
Returns money
As
Begin
 RETURN @OfferValue * CHOOSE(DATEPART(QUARTER,@OfferDate), 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25) 
END
```

Comment: thanks man..looks like it works..while I'm here..suppose I wanted to do the same thing except develop a tabular UDF that does not accept any values and calculates the commission for each employee_id?

Comment: @user2127184 Use Choose for even shorter solution

Comment: @user2127184 You don't need tabular UDF, simple select will do like `SELECT *, OfferValue_Column_Name * CHOOSE(DATEPART(QUARTER,OfferDate_Column_Name), 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25) AS alias_name FROM your_table`

Comment: Nice solution, +1 for `CHOOSE`

Comment: Thanks again @lad2025. I'm aware that I don't need tabular. I just wanted to see how it work as this is an assignment. Who knows maybe later I'll be asked to use tabular udf

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use DATEPART Function to determine the quarter - this works perfect:

```
CREATE FUNCTION OfferCommission (@OfferValue money, @OfferDate date)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE  DATEPART(QUARTER,@OfferDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN @OfferValue * 0.1
        WHEN 2 THEN @OfferValue * 0.15
        WHEN 3 THEN @OfferValue * 0.2
        WHEN 4 THEN @OfferValue * 0.25
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: @Great answer, I borrow your `DATEPART` tip and combine with `CHOOSE` function for even shorter +1  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32837286/5070879 :)

Comment: nice one - thank you! keep in mind `CHOOSE` does not exist before SQL Server 2012..

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `CASE` instead of `IF` in following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION OfferCommission (@OfferValue MONEY, @OfferDate DATE)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN @OfferDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '03/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue*0.1
                WHEN @OfferDate BETWEEN '04/01/2015' AND '06/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue*0.15
                WHEN @OfferDate BETWEEN '07/01/2015' AND '09/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue*0.2
                WHEN @OfferDate BETWEEN '09/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015' THEN @OfferValue*0.25
            END
END
```